# How to access websocket from controller or another component/services?

Tags: socket.io, nestjs, nestjs-gateways

I have a REST API, I want to send event to the client via websocket.
How to inject websocket instance in controller or another component?

Answer (score 40):

Better solution is to create **global module**. You can then emit events from any other module/controller. A. Afir approach will create multiple instances of Gateway if you try to use it in other modules.

**Note**: This is just simplest solution

Create `socket.module.ts`

```js
import { Module, Global } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SocketService } from './socket.service';

@Global()
@Module({
    controllers: [],
    providers: [SocketService],
    exports: [SocketService],
})
export class SocketModule {}
```

`socket.service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
    public socket: Server = null;
}
```

`app.gateway.ts` see `afterInit` function

```js
import { WebSocketGateway, OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect, WebSocketServer } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';
import { SocketService } from './socket/socket.service';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {

  constructor(private socketService: SocketService){}

  @WebSocketServer() public server: Server;
  private logger: Logger = new Logger('AppGateway');


  afterInit(server: Server) {
    this.socketService.socket = server;
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    this.logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]) {
    this.logger.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }
}
```

Then import `SocketModule` into AppModule and you can use `Socket service` everywhere.

Comment: (I think this should be the accepted answer) - Thanks, it really helped me. Before doing so, each new client connecting was logged more than once, probably due to the multiple instances created in each module import.

Comment: Also worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 33):

**class** `Gateway` can be injected in another component, and use the server instance.

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(
    private readonly appService: AppService,
    private readonly messageGateway: MessageGateway
  ) {}

  @Get()
  async getHello() {
    this.messageGateway.server.emit('messages', 'Hello from REST API');
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! :-) Instead of writing [solved] in your answer text, consider accepting your answer. You may do so after 48h. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: if you want to send an event to a particular cline t using this approach how do you do that?. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71349200/how-to-pass-socket-client-connection-from-nestjs-service

Comment: this was the only solution, if you inject server in a service and use it globally nest acts weird, effin' hell...

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that @Raold missed a fact in the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes):

> Gateways should not use request-scoped providers because they must act as singletons. Each gateway encapsulates a real socket and cannot be instantiated multiple times.

So it means that we can neither instantiate the gateway class multiple times nor do it explicitly using injection scopes features.

**So creating just only one gateway for one namespaces will be right and it will produce only one instance of the websocket or socket.io server.**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I offered better solution for a specific case that works. I don't think this quote is directly related to my example. It would be better if you could explain why this is fundamentally wrong and offer some example.